# KDE double clicking on folder opens the last application

Tags: kde, debian

I just installed KDE and Debian for the first time. Whenever I double click a folder on desktop, it works like undoing "Show Desktop", it opens (maximizes) the last application that was on focus. Kate, Firefox etc, whereas I expect it to open the folder with Dolphin.

This only happens on desktop, if I double click a folder within Dolphin, everything works as expected. What could be the issue here?

Thanks

**Edit:** I didn't change a setting but currently it does open the folder but also maximizes the other applications on its background.. And now I realize double clicking a text file also does the same thing.. Maximizes all applications and opens the file on Kate in the foreground. Maybe double click is somehow binded to "show all windows" or something? I didn't change any default shortcuts.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @guiverc thank you, noted. I didn't know about those ones, and since this is not directly about the OS but the DE, I thought any Ubuntu user may experience this as well. I will make sure its on-topic next time though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, clicking a desktop icon does open the folder as expected, and your problem is that it also restores other windows?

This is expected behavior if you use "Show Desktop": It shows the desktop window, and when leaving that window, other previously visible windows become visible again as well.

If you want all windows to be minimized when entering the desktop, use "Minimize All" instead: Right-click on the desktop icon > Show Alternatives > Minimize All.

Comment: Yes! It does work. But this is very unintuitive. "Minimize all" should be the default behaviour of it, as in all other DE's :) Thanks though!

Comment: You can file a feature request at bugs.kde.org to change for the default to be changed.

Comment: Good idea, although I have no idea how to do that :) Can you please tell me which product is this related to? (Someone can also go ahead and file the bug for me :p)

Comment: Product plasmashell, component Show Desktop/Minimize All. In general, it's fine if you put it wherever you think it fits best, bug triagers will correct it if necessary.

Comment: Done! Thanks so much for your help :) (Sorry I don't have enough rep to upvote your comments)